# How to install mysql 5.5.34 completely from shell?

Tags: mysql

I'm try to install mysql 5.5.34 from shell in my server, I'm new for linux.Can anyone explain it simply?

Answer (score 0):

To install, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

Or download you desired version from [here](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/5.5.html#downloads), and once downloaded, navigate to the downloaded foleder (Probably the Downloads folder), and run the command below:

```
sudo dpkg -i <package_name>.deb
```

You may also need to install the `libaio` library if it is not already installed

```
sudo apt-get install libaio1
```

Comment: When i use sudo apt-get install mysql-server it tries to dowload mysql 5.1 ..what i do .i did apt-get update

Comment: I just tried it using the same command, and I got version 5.5.  See [Image](http://ubuntuone.com/57Y3h78J8byhCDsCHy4sMj). Which   Ubuntu release are you running?